# hive insert overwrite directory stored as parquet created columns with default names

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

If I run a hive insert overwrite query as follows to store the data in parquet format then column name is getting defaulted to _col0. How can i avoid it and enforce the column names that are in select clause.

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "SOME-LOCATION"
STORED AS PARQUET
SELECT name FROM employee;

-- the resulting parquet file gets created with column name as "_col0" instead of "name"

is there a way to overcome this problem by passing in some properties to the serde?

```
hive> select * from employee;
OK
employee.id     employee.name   employee.salary
100     john doe        99999
101     jane doe        88888


hive> insert overwrite directory '/tmp/empdata' stored as parquet select name from employee;

scala> spark.read.parquet("/tmp/empdata").printSchema
root
 |-- _col0: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Column indexes work fine only when both table definition in metastore and parquet schema match exactly, or when there are only additions to the end of a schema. Whereas when column names are used there are no problems with schema evolution.
Here are three cases, that work when `hive.parquet.use-column-names = true` and break with the default `hive.parquet.use-column-names = false`:

- the column is added to a schema in metastore, but not exists in a parquet file.
- the column is added to parquet file, but not exists in a schema in metastore.
- columns order in a schema in metastore doesn't match with an order in a parquet file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not sure I understand what you are proposing. I am looking to create a parquet file in a directory based on result set from a select query on a table. I also ran set; to list all hive parameters and  could not find hive.parquet.use-column-names.